# .NET String formatting -What does the # mean to the left of the decimal point?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I have a need to format a numeric string to a maximum of 2 places either side of the decimal point, even if it means truncating or chopping off the leading digits (it's a long story, don't ask).   On the MSDN it *implies* this can be done with the pound sign (#):

> "The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol.
>   If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the pound sign appears in the format string, that digit is copied to
>   the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in
>   the result string."

But in practice that only seems to work to the right of the decimal point.  If I do this:

```
String s = " Test - " + String.Format("format0 = {0:0.##}, format1 = {1:#.##}, format2 = {2:##.###}",321.2345, 321.2345, 321.2345);
```

I get this output for s:

> " Test - format0 = 321.23, format1 = 321.23, format2 = 321.235"

... note that "0.##" and "#.##" produced the same output.    So what **exactly** does the "#" mean when it's to the left of the decimal point?

Comment: FYI, this formatting has nothing to do with C#. It's .NET Framework string formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To paraphrase the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD) that you cited, the `#` makes the digit in that position optional. If the number has a significant digit in that position, it will be printed; otherwise it will not.

Take a look at this example:

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}, {0:#.##}", 0.5)
```

This will output

```
0.5, .5
```

Or perhaps a more clear example:

```
String.Format("{0:000.000}, {0:###.###}", 0.5)
```

This will output

```
000.500, .5
```

Answer (score 1):

`0.##` and `#.##` don't produce the same output.

```
0m.ToString("0.##") // returns "0"

0m.ToString("#.##") // returns ""

0m.ToString("#.#0") // returns ".00"
```

Comment: I meant they produce the same output in my example.

Comment: But your question was "So what exactly does the "#" mean when it's to the left of the decimal point?"